# parented/constrained object transform lags when moving character in unity3D

Tags: transformation, raycasting

Hi I have a simple raycast-base gun that emits particles along it's path to fake bullets. Whenever I move the camera/character- the particles are misaligned, as well as anything else I try to modify its transform with in scripting. I believe the culprit to be slerp but I am not sure how else I can write it. I've attached the script for any details. Any ideas would be awesome, this issue has been plaguing me all day.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class raycast : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform mainTransform;
    public GameObject mesh_input;
    public GameObject path_obj;
    public float spread;
    public float range;
    //right now rate and pathtime are tied together, which means the gun fires again after each successive hit
    //we need to separate these into individual components so we can fire many shots but have them take time
    //to reach their destination
    public float rate = 0.5F;
    private float nextFireTime = 0.0F;
    public int ammo = 600;
    private enemy target;
    private Rigidbody enemycollider;
    public static Transform particles;
    public Transform muzzle;
    public GameObject muzzleflash;

    void OnGUI (){
      GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 200, 20), "Weapon: Color Pistol");
      GUI.Box (new Rect (10,40, 200, 20), "Ammo: " + ammo.ToString());
      GUI.Box (new Rect (10,70, 200, 20), "Rate: " +  ((((60 / rate)/60)*100F)/100F) + "bps");
      GUI.Box (new Rect (10,100, 250, 20), "z = decrease rate, x = increase rate ");
    }


    IEnumerator MoveThis(Transform origin, Vector3 destinationPosition, float period, Transform obj, RaycastHit hit) {
      float t = 0F;
      print ("coroutine: " + origin.transform.position);
      obj.transform.position = origin.transform.position;
      while (t < 1) {
        obj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (obj.transform.position, destinationPosition, t);
        t += Time.deltaTime / period;
        yield return null;
      }
      GameObject prefab = Instantiate (mesh_input, destinationPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
      float rand = Random.Range (0F,3F);
      prefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(rand,rand,rand);
      prefab.transform.localPosition = prefab.transform.localPosition + new Vector3 (Random.Range (-1*spread,spread), 0, Random.Range (-1*spread,spread));
      //  print ("Hit!");
      ammo -= 1;
      if (hit.collider.tag == "enemy") {
        target = hit.collider.GetComponent<enemy> ();
        target.addDamage(51);
        enemycollider = hit.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        enemycollider.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(-50,1,0) * Vector3.Angle(gameObject.transform.position, hit.point), hit.point);
      }
    }

    void fire(RaycastHit hit, Transform trans){

      GameObject path = Instantiate (path_obj, mainTransform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
      Transform particles = path.transform.Find ("mover");
      StartCoroutine (MoveThis(trans,hit.point,rate, particles, hit));

    }

    void raycaster(bool buttoncheck, Transform trans){
          RaycastHit hit;
          Vector3 fwd = mainTransform.TransformDirection (Vector3.up);
          if (Physics.Raycast (mainTransform.position, fwd, out hit, range) && buttoncheck == true) {
        //      print ("Hit detected");
        //      print (hit.distance.ToString ());
              fire (hit, trans);  
        Debug.DrawLine (mainTransform.position, hit.point, new Color (0, 0, 1, 1));
          }
      }



    void Awake(){
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
      mainTransform = muzzle.transform;
      print ("Fixed: " + mainTransform.position.ToString ());
      bool fire1 = Input.GetButton ("Fire1");
      bool fire2 = Input.GetButton ("Fire2");
      if (fire1 == true && ammo != 0 && Time.time > nextFireTime) {
        Instantiate (muzzleflash, muzzle.transform.position, transform.rotation);
        nextFireTime = Time.time + rate;
        raycaster(fire1, mainTransform);        
      }
      if (fire2 == true) {  
        ammo = Mathf.Clamp(600,0,600);
      }
      if (Input.GetKeyDown("z") && rate >= 0){
        rate = Mathf.Clamp (rate + .01F, .01F, .99F);
      }
      if (Input.GetKeyDown ("x") && rate <= 1){
        rate = Mathf.Clamp(rate - .01F, .01F , .99F);
      }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Adding comments to your code would help. There are certainly some odd things about your code that need explaining.